# process composition and exceptions

Tags: scala

How can I catch exceptions from external processes that are combined with #&& etc.. ?

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._     
scala> try{ "throw " ! }catch{ case e: Exception => }
res1: AnyVal = ()
scala> try{ "throw " #&& "ls" ! }catch{ case e: Exception => }
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "throw": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already do. Try

```
try {
 val x = "throw" #&& "ls" !
} catch {
 case x => println("caught")
}
```

The `!` just logs the exception to the console, which is a bit confusing when you see it in the REPL, but it does not crash.

Comment: True, my program didn't crash. Its just the stacktrace that gets to std error also during a normal program run, not just the REPL. It was confusing me.